# Angular JS tabs CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to build a tab page with my website using AngularJS only. I saw somewhere that it is not advisable to augment AngularJS with Jquery.

I have difficulties in remove the line between the tab and the tab content. E.g. When tab 1 is chosen, then the line below tab 1 will disappear.

Can anyone help with the CSS question?

Thank you.

My HTML

```
<html ng-app>
<div class="tabgroup" ng-init="tab=1">
<div class="tab" ng-click="tab = 1">tab1</div>
<div class="tab" ng-click="tab = 2">tab2</div>
</div>
<div class="tabcontents">   
<div ng-show="tab == 1">
    tab 1 contents
</div>
<div ng-show="tab == 2">
    tab 2 contents
</div>
</html>
</div>
```

Current CSS

```
.tabgroup{
background:white; 
}
.tab{
color:black;    
display:inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 5px;
}
.tabcontents{
border: 1px solid #000000;    
padding: 5px;
}
```

This is my  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DBKL/1/)

Comment: Your demo seems to be working. Your best bet would be to turn this into a directive. Take a look at bootstrap UI for ideas. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) where we add a class (for instance `selected`) on the "selected" tab.  For example:

```
<div class="tab" ng-class="{selected: tab==1}" ng-click="tab = 1">tab1</div>
<div class="tab" ng-class="{selected: tab==2}" ng-click="tab = 2">tab2</div>
```

The above`{selected: tab==1}` says to add the class "selected" if the condition "tab == 1" is true.

And then add css for the `selected` tab.  For instance to remove the bottom border on the selected item:

```
.selected {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DBKL/3/)

Comment: How do I remove the line between tab1 and tabcontent directly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by directly?  Even if it's not selected?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-class` to conditionally add or remove a classname.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DBKL/4/)

```
<div class="tab" ng-click="tab = 1" ng-class="{tabactive:tab === 1}">tab1</div>
<div class="tab" ng-click="tab = 2" ng-class="{tabactive:tab === 2}">tab2</div>
```

Then include the class you wish to add when the condition is met.

```
.tabactive{
    border-bottom:0px solid #000;
}
```